# Extract values from Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

I need to extract Asia from this array. How can i do that. Here is a sample array?
This is javascript. i need to extract Asia from first index. Help required.

```
var myData = new Array(['Asia', 437, 520],['Middle East', 20, 31],['Aus/Oceania', 19,21]);
```

Comment: Read a [JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), especially [about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object). Make sure you understand at least the basics of a language before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myData[0][0]` will work or else you can try like this

```
var myData = new Array(['Asia', 437, 520],['Middle East', 20, 31],['Aus/Oceania', 19,21]);
var arr=myData[0];
var spl=arr.shift();
alert(spl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could access it via myData[0][0]

Answer (score 0):

You could access it via `myData[0][0]` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `myData[0][0]` and doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

`myData[0][0]` will give you `Asia`.